# Mongodb how to query result as plain array of one propery

Tags: mongodb

I I had in mongodb colleciton documents like:

Documents in collection (each has name property):

> [{   name: 'Alex', .. }, {   name: 'Jane', .. } ... ]

How can I query db to get the result simply mapping the name property:

> ['Ale', 'Jane', ...]

?

Comment: Not really that clear to me. Do you mean a "collection" or an **array** within the "documents" in your collection. It is also especially hard when you do not show us **what** doesn't actually work.

Comment: updated OP, I just don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would want to use is [query projections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations-introduction/#projections).

> Queries in MongoDB return all fields in all matching documents by default. To limit the amount of data that MongoDB sends to applications, include a projection in the queries.

For your example, your query would look something like this:

```
db.people.find( {}, { "name": 1 } )
```

This will extract all documents but only return the name attribute (and `_id`) for each one. To remove the `_id` attribute as well, you would have to explicitly specify that you don't want it:

```
db.people.find( {}, { "name": 1, "_id": 0 } )
```

---

In order to retrieve all of the names in one array, you could use a `forEach` function to assemble the data:

```
var names = [];
db.people.find( {}, { "name": 1, "_id": 0 } ).forEach( function( doc ){
  names.push( doc.name );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to return name field, what I need is to get plain array as result, updated OP

Comment: And I wan't it do do without aditional javascirpt in callback

Comment: Sure thing, just wanted to give some more background info for future visitors.

Comment: May I ask why? This seems to be the simplest solution to retrieve all the data you requested...

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Lix seems to have asked you some clear questions, but did not **tag** you in the comments so you are not seeing them

Comment: I wonder if it is possible. To reduce amound of data that comes from mongoDB (collection is big, and I need only one propery value)

Comment: @WHITECOLOR - that is what query projection is for (as I have stated in my answer).

Comment: Can you advice how to use it to get result I need?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Queries will always return documents. What you are wanting to do is do some manipulation on the documents that are returned in order to accumulate only the name property. This is what my example code does.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR - also, you still haven't answered my question. If there are some additional constraints with your issue, please define them in your original question.

Comment: Ok, I got it "query always return documents". Thanks.